# I have no option to upload videos to my reviews

Tags: google-maps

I don't understand why I can't  upload any **video** to my google reviews. I tried it from PC or even from Phone.

Few months past I was able to upload video but now I can't.
I didn't received any ban or restriction or warning or anything else like this.
I didn't find any explanation for this issue on Google.

In [Google maps help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2622947?hl=en&visit_id=637961478720732936-2997763964&p=newmaps_addaphoto&rd=1) is mentioned that the upload of video is possible but i do not see option to upload video in my reviews.

[image: Google maps help - screenshot]

Its mentioned on Google maps help
[image: Add new review - option to add video is missing - screenshot]

However under add new review - the option to add video is missing
[image: Only image extentions are available - screenshot]

Only image extensions are available for uploads.

**Does anybody know anything about this issue?**

Comment: what is the video format you are trying to upload?

Comment: I can't upload any video and any format is not supported as you can see in last screenshot in my first post.
Despite of this I tried to select "All Files (*.*)" and then I chose  .M4V and .MOV and .MP4 video formats but without success. At example .M4V video has 11 sec. duration, 13,2 MB, 1920x1080, 30 FPS, 10103 kbps overall.  
https://i.imgur.com/TSO59CN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received help on Google Local Guides platform.
You must upload video separately from the review and after upload the video will be merged with your review.

Upload of video is provided by button "Add a photo":
[image: Guide]